# Program crashes after reading from binary file and assigning to matrix

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I have an assignment, to create a program that solves 9x9 sudoku puzzle. The specifications are the following:

- Filename must be given to command line as a parameter (EDIT: `argv[0]` isn't necessary, just need to input from keyboard with `scanf` function)
- File must be binary
- All arrays must be dynamically allocated
- Binary file contains numbers that determine the coords and the desired number
  e.g 367 means 3rd row 6th column and number 7

My program allocates a 2D array dynamically, then allocates space to save the filename, then opens the binary file to read data. Using `printf` to debug my program it seems that data gets saved to `importedData` array appropriately and when assigning those data on sudoku puzzle, either the program crashes, or doesn't assign the values properly. Here is my code:

Sudoku.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sudokulib.h"

#define MALLOC_ERROR 0xFF
#define FILE_NOT_FOUND 0xFFF

int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
    char **matrix;
    int i,j; 
    int row,column,num;
    FILE * fp;
    char * filename;
    char * importedData;
    matrix=(char **)malloc(9*sizeof(char *));
    if (!matrix)
    exit(MALLOC_ERROR);
    for (i=0;i<9;++i)
    {
        matrix[i]=(char *)malloc(9*sizeof(char));
        if (!matrix[i])
        exit(MALLOC_ERROR);
    } 
    initSudoku(matrix);
    printf ("Give me the name of data file: ");
    filename=(char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    if (!filename)
    exit(MALLOC_ERROR);
    scanf("%s",filename);
    fp=fopen(filename,"rb");
    if (!fp)
    {
        printf ("File not found\n");
        exit(FILE_NOT_FOUND);
    }
    importedData=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*81*3);
    if (!importedData)
    exit (MALLOC_ERROR);
    fread(importedData,1,243,fp);
    i=0;
while (importedData[i] != ' ' && importedData[i+1] != ' ' && importedData[i+2] != ' ' && importedData[i] >= '1' && importedData[i+1] >= '1' && importedData[i+2] >= '1' && importedData[i] <= '9' && importedData[i+1] <= '9' && importedData[i+2] <= '9')
    {
        row=importedData[i] - 48; /* Convert from ascii code to number */
        column=importedData[i+1] - 48;
        num=importedData[i+2] - 48;
        matrix[row][column]=num;
        i=i+3;  
    } 
    printf("Sudoku after importing data:\n\n");
    printSudoku(matrix);
    system("pause");
    if (solvePuzzle(matrix))
    {
        printSudoku(matrix);
    }
    else
    printf ("Puzzle has no solution\n");
    fclose(fp);
    free(filename);
    for (i=0;i<9;++i)
    {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

Sudokulib.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Function Prototypes Begin Here */

void printSudoku(char **);
void initSudoku(char **);
int checkRow(char **,int,int);
int checkCol(char **,int,int);
int check3x3(char **,int,int,int);
int checkIfEmpty(char **,int*,int*);
int solvePuzzle (char **);

/* Function Prototypes End Here */

void printSudoku(char ** Mat)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<9;++i)
    {
        printf ("-------------------\n");
        printf("|");
        for (j=0;j<9;++j)
        {
            printf("%d|",Mat[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
    printf ("-------------------\n");
}

void initSudoku(char ** Mat)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<9;++i)
    for (j=0;j<9;++j)
    Mat[i][j]=0;
} 


int checkRow (char ** Mat,int row, int num) // if row is free returns 1 else returns 0
{
    int col;
    for (col = 0; col < 9; col++)
    {
        if (Mat[row][col] == num-48) 
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int checkCol (char ** Mat,int col , int num) // if column is free returns 1 else returns 0
{
    int row;
    for (row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        if (Mat[row][col] == num-48) 
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int check3x3 (char ** Mat, int row, int col, int num) // if number doesnt exist in the 3x3 grid returns 1 else returns 0
{
    row = (row/3) * 3; // set to first row in the grid
    col = (col/3) * 3; // set to first col in the grid
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) // grid is 3x3
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (Mat[row+i][col+j] == num-48)
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int checkIfEmpty(char ** Mat, int *row, int *col) // if a block of the entire puzzle is empty returns 1 else returns 0 also saves the target row and column it found empty
{
        for (*row = 0; *row < 9; *row++)
        {
            for (*col = 0; *col < 9; *col++)
            {
                if (Mat[*row][*col] == 0)
                return 1;
            }
        }
    return 0;
}

int solvePuzzle (char ** Mat)
{
    int num;
    int row;
    int col;
    row = 0;
    col = 0;
    if (!checkIfEmpty(Mat,&row,&col)) // if puzzle is solved return 1
    return 1;
    for (num = 1; num < 9; num++)
    {
        if (checkRow (Mat,row,num) && checkCol (Mat,col,num) && check3x3 (Mat,row,col,num))
        {
            Mat[row][col] = num-48;
        }
    if (solvePuzzle (Mat))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    Mat[row][col] = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help to resolve the aforementioned issue is appreciated.
Also keep in mind that `int solvePuzzle()` is not quite finished and any suggestions to improve this function are welcome.

EDIT: Here are the contents of binary file `data2.bin` that causes wrong assignment

```
142156177191216228257289311329364375418422441484534546562579625663682698739743787794824855883896
```

Output:

```
Give me the name of data file: data2.bin
Sudoku after importing data:

-------------------
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
-------------------
|0|0|0|0|2|6|0|7|0|
-------------------
|0|6|8|0|0|7|0|0|9|
-------------------
|0|1|9|0|0|0|4|5|0|
-------------------
|0|8|2|0|1|0|0|0|4|
-------------------
|0|0|0|4|6|0|2|9|0|
-------------------
|0|0|5|0|0|0|3|0|2|
-------------------
|0|0|0|9|3|0|0|0|7|
-------------------
|0|0|4|0|0|5|0|0|3|
-------------------
Press any key to continue . . .
```

EDIT 2: Found out that if a very small binary file is used that contains very few data e.g. `123245321` works fine, but if data exceed 9 bytes, then the puzzle gets messed up.

Comment: [mcve], please. *You* need to determine where the problem is first.

Comment: Got a crash? Great time to strap the debugger on to your executable and see what's going on internally.

Comment: In the `while` where you parse the file data, you read past the end of the array. Try `while (importedData[i] && isdigit(importedData[i])....`

Comment: Also, I don't see any zeros in the data, so you probably want to offset row and column by -1.

Comment: Quote: "Binary file contains numbers that determine the coords and the desired number e.g 367 means 3rd row 6th column and number 7" oh, dear... will teacher never learn

Comment: OT: "My program allocates a 2D array dynamically..." No, it doesn't. It allocates a 1D array of pointers where each pointer points to a 1D array. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays for the correct way

Comment: OT: "Filename must be given to command line as a parameter" But you read it using `scanf`. Instead you should take it from `argv`

Comment: OT: Never - like in never ever - do `scanf("%s",filename);` Always put a limit like `scanf("%99s",filename);`

Comment: @MichaelBeer Actually you are right. This is not a true binary file, it's just a file created with fopen(filename,"wb") and giving numbers using fwrite. In this case it's just called binary due to the .bin extension.

Comment: Did you get that file from the teacher? It does look like a binary file for this purpose.

Comment: @4386427 No, i created this myself. All you need to do is open a binary file using fopen and input numbers with fwrite. It;s not a true binary file, it's called so due to .bin extension.

Comment: @4386427 Thanks for the link that was a good read. Sadly i can't use this way of allocating as the project requires to allocate the array using a char **. BTW when i said that "filename must be given as a parameter from command line", i didn't mean as argv[0], all i need to do is just to enter it from keyboard using scanf.  Will edit to clarify.

Comment: Since it's not a "binary" file, you could try `while (3 == fscanf(fp, "%1d%1d%1d", &row, &col, &num)) ;`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp But am i reading integers from my "binary" file this way? Because my teacher told me that fread fills the desired buffer with raw bytes (chars) and in this case those data should be handled as 1 byte integers. Actually his words were "chars are just integers that have less range and take less space on ram" , but i find that hard to believe. If that's the case why doesn't C call chars as tinyints ?

Comment: @JohnM. The basic problem here is that the direction from your teacher is all wrong. The sentence: "Binary file contains numbers that determine the coords and the desired number e.g 367 means 3rd row 6th column and number 7" is completely useless as a specification. It should at least specify the size of each object but still it's useless without an encoding specifier. Anyway - if it was true binary, you would not do the `- 48` stuff.

Comment: @4386427 Understood. Wish i could do it this way but you know... specifications are specifications... (more like restrictions in this case i would say).

Comment: regarding the contents of `sudokulib.h`  a header file should NOT contain code (but yours does)  A header file should only contain function signatures, data definitions, macros

Comment: when writing an error message that resulted from a call to a C library function, call `perror( "your error message" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  This will properly output the error message to `stderr` and output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that arrays are zero indexed. So you need to subtract one more to get the correct index, example:

```
row=importedData[i] - 48 - 1;
```

Also notice that you have too few numbers in your file. There is only 96 but you need 243.

Further...

Look at this:

```
importedData=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*81*3);
...
fread(importedData,1,243,fp);
```

now you have 243 chars in `importedData` (something that you should check by looking at the return code from `fread`. In your case the file only has 96 chars (bad...) but let's just assume it worked).

Then you do:

```
    i=0;
while (importedData[i] != ' ' && 
       importedData[i+1] != ' ' && 
       importedData[i+2] != ' ' && 
       importedData[i] >= '1' && 
       importedData[i+1] >= '1' && 
       importedData[i+2] >= '1' && 
       importedData[i] <= '9' && 
       importedData[i+1] <= '9' && 
       importedData[i+2] <= '9')
{
    ....
}
```

So if the 243 chars that you read all made the condition above true, you'll keep on reading beyond the memory allocated for `importedData`. So you have undefined behavior.

You need to add:

```
&& i < 243;
```

to the condition.

BTW: All these hard code numbers are bad. Use a `#define` instead.

BTW: Don't do

```
row=importedData[i] - 48 -1;
```

but

```
row=importedData[i] - '0' - 1;
```

Comment: In order to check for number of bytes should i check the return value of fread? Is it considered good practice?

Comment: @JohnM. Exactly

Comment: Thanks A LOT! All i needed to do was to substract 1 from row and column like you said and it worked. How stupid of me to forget to substract 1 from indexes.

Comment: Something i would like to note also is the fact that number 243 is produced from multiplying 9*9*3 (9 rows * 9 columns * (2 coords + 1 number)). Tried to find a better solution but i can't think of anything better as my teacher demands that it should even solve puzzles that have already been solved. Looks pretty dumb though.

Comment: @JohnM. Do `#define ROWS 9 #define COLUMNS ...` and use these defines in your code instead of hard code numbers